# how to remove burg-pc error

Tags: 14.04, software-center, software-installation, burg

When applying any software from Ubuntu Software Center it tells me that:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 burg-pc
```

The software installed, but because of the error I need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed it by synaptic I install this software then I choose burg-PC from it then I applied its remove options.